# dynamic Binding to ToolbarItem Icon to switch Images from File

Tags: android, xaml, xamarin.forms, icons, toolbaritems

I am trying to build a Toolbar using MVVM with a Filter Icon. when you click it you navigate somewhere where you set a filter and then get navigated back. IF the Filter is active with selected Items I want the Toolbar Icon to be a different image now.

BUT the Binding doesn't seem to work.
Whenever I set the Icon to just a string of my Image in files like "Filter.png" the Toolbar does only display the Text "FILTER".
When I convert the value I bound to a FileImageSource I get the error

So how do I do this correctly? I already tried using a converter but same result. My code is:

XAML:

```
 <ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
    <ToolbarItem Order="Primary" Icon="{Binding FilterIconActive}" Text="Filter" Priority="0" Command="{Binding FilterCommand}" />
</ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
```

MyViewModel:

```
private string _filterIcon;

public string FilterIcon
{
    get => _filterIcon;
    set => SetProperty(ref _filterIcon, value);
}

                FilterIcon = _selectedFilter.Any() ? "FilterDone.png" : "Filter.png";
```

As I said already, changing the itemtype from string to FileImageSource since Icon is of type MenuItem.Icon doesn't work either. Thanks guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that you are binding the `FilterIconActive` property whereas you are making the change in `FilterIcon` property.

Another thing that I noticed is you are not using the [INotifyPropertyChanged's](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/how-to-implement-the-inotifypropertychanged-interface) event to notify your property that there was a change in its value.

Comment: oh wow now this is embarrassing. I really did Bind to the wrong Item. INotifyPropertyChanged is not shown here but I use Prisms BindableBase.